# Subplot iterating through cell arrays

Tags: matlab, subplot

I'm trying to iterate over my `cell` array and sub-plot each image that's stored there.

See my code:

```
for i=1:96
    for j=1:9
        subplot(ceil(sqrt(960)),ceil(sqrt(960)),i)
        imshow(trainingData{2}{i}{j})
    end
end
```

I have 96 cells (in `i` column) that each contain 10 images (`j` column) (of which the first 9 I want to plot).

I know it's pretty pointless because they're so small, but I've started it and seems I can't get it working how I thought, I'd really like to know where I'm going wrong before I just drop it. 
(also the program may have less images in the future anyway).

So far, it's only sub-ploting 96 entries; it should be 864:

[image: faces]

In case my data structure confuses you, here's a little explanation:

`trainingData` is a Mat file which I load, the first column needs a 1 if you want to access a persons name, or a 2 if you want to their images. The second column contains 96 people (from 1 to 96. The third column is 10 pictures of the person.

```
eg. trainingData{2}{56}{7} accesses the 56th persons 7th photo.
```

I'm sure many will see this as an unorthodox data structure, but that's how I thought of doing it at the time. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem seems to be the line

```
subplot(ceil(sqrt(960)),ceil(sqrt(960)),i)
```

which causes the 9 images in the inner loop to be overwritten in the same subplot (so only the last one is seen). Change it to

```
subplot(ceil(sqrt(960)),ceil(sqrt(960)),(i-1)*9+j)
```

so that all subplots are used.